# select from list which has same code

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a problem in getting the values for the below.
I have a table called Retailers which contains Id,Description,Language and Code
I declared  a list in my application which contains all the retailers list

```
var retailers = new List<Retailer>();
```

Now I need to add results of two retailers with same code so I am trying to do below and I am sure I am doing something wrong.

```
foreach (var retailer in retailers)
{
    if (retailer.LanguageId != null)
    {
        // Here I am trying to findout if there are any other retailers who 
        // has same code if true then I need entire row of that retailer

        **var retailerWithSameUacode = !retailers.Select(item => item.Code == retailerCode).SingleOrDefault();**
        if (retailerWithSameUacode != null)
        {
            // Do something 
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated !

Comment: you need [Where extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.where(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @GrantWinney My intension is If I found a retailer with same Code then I need to conctenate those 2 retailer results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think I entirely understand your question, but from your code comment and your attempt to select a retailer with the same code, I present to you the following..

To get the first retailer out of your list with a code that matches the current retailer, you would need to do this:

```
Retailer retailerWithMatchingCode = retailers.Where(r => r.Code == retailer.Code).FirstOrDefault();
```

You can then check the retailerWithMatchingCode object for a null value.  If you just want to know if a retailer with a matching code exists, this is what you would do:

```
if (retailers.Any(r => r.Code == retailer.Code))
//Do something..
```

To get a list of retailers who have a matching "Code" property value, you would need to do this:

```
List<Retailer> retailersWithMatchingCode = retailers.Where(r => r.Code == retailer.Code).ToList();
```

Please note that this code is untested.

Comment: The Where is redundant in:

Retailer retailerWithMatchingCode = retailers.Where(r => r.Code == retailer.Code).FirstOrDefault();

Just use:

Retailer retailerWithMatchingCode = retailers.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Code == retailer.Code);

Comment: @Jibberish, you are absolutely correct, and I am guilty of this redundancy more often than I care to admit -- I just feel like it's more readable for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

```
var retailerWithSameUacode = retailers
    .Where(item => item.LanguageId != null && item.Code == retailerCode)
    .ToList();
foreach (var item in retailerWithSameUacode) 
{
    // Do something
}
```